# Graphing function with polar coordinate

Tags: graphing-functions, polar-coordinates

I am studying polar coordinates and I am not understanding what's the practical method for graphing this relation:

$$r = \frac{1}{2} + \sin \theta, \text{for } 0 < \theta < 2\pi$$.

I plotted using [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PolarPlot%20r%20%3D%200.5%20%2B%20sint), but I don't understand what happened in the interval $\pi < \theta < {3\pi}/{2}$ (I mean, where did the inner loop come from?).

Comment: You should clarify what your question is.

Comment: I don't understand how to plot this graph in the specific interval: $\pi < \theta < 2\pi$.

Comment: I'm assuming you need to know how to do so on Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: No, I want to understand how to graph this relation with a pencil (I don't understand how it works in this interval)

Comment: I'd use a table of values, write down a few values of $\theta$ on the left, and compute the corresponding values of $r$. Then plot those points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate x and y in a table separately for

$$ x = (1/2 + \sin \theta) \cos \theta, $$
$$ y = (1/2 + \sin \theta)\sin \theta. $$

You notice that not always we have a single $r$ for a given $ \theta$ for the entire domain. In this case double angle $\theta $ gives rise to another $r$ after further rotation.

Likewise $ r = \sin 2\theta $ gives rise to four leaves in the plot.

Comment: Thank you!! That was really helpful.